# C# - initial.object within argument?

Tags: c#, programming-languages

Is it possible to initialize an object that I want to pass as an argument without writing it on a special line?:

```
String a="test";
a.TrimStart(new char [] X=['a'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, but you can't assign name to it. Try:

```
a.TrimStart(new char[] {'a'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.TrimStart(new char[] { 'a' });
```

You can even leave out the "char":

```
a.TrimStart(new[] { 'a' });
```

Comment: Or simply:
a.TrimStart(new[] { 'a' });